# How to obtain the layers on the program?

Tags: layers

I search the layers of blender, but I can't find them...

Can you help me? I am an absolute beginner on the program.

Thanks a lot by hoping you will help me and... see you soon so!

Comment: Did you go through the introductory videos on using Blender https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6, or check the documentation https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/layers.html?highlight=layers#working-with-layers ?

Comment: what are you trying to do?  What do you mean by obtaining the layers?

Comment: Yes for the first... but not for the second.

Comment: I tried... but they don't appear because - it seems - that they are in one different place on Blender 8.0.

Comment: Layers don't exist anymore in 2.8, you have Render Layers but it's another topic, so if you follow tutorials with layers you can't use them in 2.8, instead you need to use Collections, you begin to have tutorials about 2.8, here about Collections: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_yIGGhubZs